# Keeping some of the elements in a list

Tags: python, list

I have been trying to figure out how to find specific words in a list then move these to a new list. Say i have  :

```
a = ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

and I only want to have a, c and e. Is it possible to do this without using .remove() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I hope I understood your question right.  You want to only select the contents of one list if they are in another list.  You might use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Here's an example playing at the interactive prompt.

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> [x for x in a if x in ['a', 'c', 'e' ]]
['a', 'c', 'e']
```

or with clearer naming

```
>>> list = ['a','b','c','d','e', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'c']
>>> wanted = ['a', 'c', 'e' ]
>>> [x for x in list if x in wanted]
['a', 'c', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'c']
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the 2nd square brackets?

Comment: @Gaddi It's a list containing the element you want to keep. It might be more readable as a tuple instead of a list... `[x for x in a if x in ('a', 'c', 'e')]`

Comment: @Gaddi  - I reformatted the second part so the different lists should now be clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) builtin function:

```
>>> lst = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>>
>>> def keep(item):
...     # Implement whatever criterion you need here
...     return item in ('a', 'c', 'e')
...
>>> filter(keep, lst)
['a', 'c', 'e']
```

`filter` will simply return a filtered sequence (a list in your case) without modifying the input sequence.

`keep` in this example just needs to be a function that, given an item, decides whether to keep it or not by returning `True` (keep) or `False` (discard).

---

Note: As pointed out by @tobias_k, in Python 3 `filter()` will return an iterator. So if you actually do need a list (not just an iterable), you'd need to pass it to the `list()` constructor like this:

```
newlist = list(filter(keep, lst))
```

Comment: Note: In Python 3, `filter` returns an iterator.

Comment: is there a way to do it without the use of a function?

Comment: @Gaddi: You could do the same using a lambda expression, which is basically a function without a name: `new = filter(lambda x: x in ('a', 'c', 'e'), lst)`. But you need to give `filter` *some* sort of callable that decides whether to keep the item or not.